# Hive regex split a string in to two different fields

Tags: regex, hadoop, hive

my record is like:

```
0x0000110PPPP111KZY0 H123456789 XYZ 000000000000000000607532030000607532000060753203002014101707199999
```

I am searching for a regex where i can split first 3 char `0x0` in to one field in a hive table and the rest `000110PPPP111KZY0` in to second field and so on fixed length file and no delimiter.

Comment: can you give example of the result you want? at least 2 or 3

Comment: how you want the third field? please provide sample result for the record given.

Answer (score 1):

I have no experience with hadoop or hive, however the following regex will work with what I believe you're looking for.

`/(\dx\d)(.*)/` This will capture/split `0x0` into the first capture group, and everything afterwards into the second capture group. If you only want the numbers/letters following the 0x0 number (so none of the `H123456789` or trailing words and letters), use `/(\dx\d)([^ ]*)/`

If I misunderstood what you're looking for, can you just clarify the exact section of that code you provided that you'd like to select and/or capture? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
Select 
  regexp_extract(data, '^(\\dx\\d).*', 1), 
  regexp_extract(data, '^\\dx\\d(.*)', 1) 
from (Select '0x0000110PPPP111KZY0 ' as data) a;
```

This code returns a Hive row with two fields:

```
0x0 000110PPPP111KZY0
```